# Login php verification Problem with Xampp

Tags: php, html, sql, xampp

I am trying to verify the login of a website using php by querying the database table . It is creating an error parsing the session in the login.php. The website is all hosted on XAMPP. This is just a trial website. This is my first time coding in PHP, honestly just a week in.

I've tried to modify the $global variables. Is it because xampp is running on MariaDB instead of sql, but that makes no sense because this is PHP and the create_table

```
This is the login
<html form
<div class="loginbox">
<img src="images/log.png" class="log">
<h1> Login </h1>
<form  action="login.php" method="post">

<div class="name">
<label for ="name"> Username/E-mail:</label>
<input type="text" id="name" name="username" placeholder="Enter  
 Username/E-mail">    
</div>

<div class="password">
<label for="password"> Password:</label>
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" 
 placeholder="Enter Password">
</div>

<div>
<button type="submit"  >Login</button>
</div>
</form> 

</div>

And this is the table created for signup.
    $persontable= "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users.Person(
    Userid                  INTEGER UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Firstname               VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Lastname                VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Username                VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Email                   VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Password                VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Dateofbirth             DATE        NOT NULL,
    Address                 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    City                    VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Zipcode                 VARCHAR(20),)";

    if (!(mysqli_query($handler,$persontable))){
        die("Account has not been created successfully:". 
    mysqli_error($handler)); }
    else{echo "Account has been created succesfully"}

And this is the code of login<php
  <?php
  $servername = "127.0.0.1";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "";
  /** Define variable to perform connection to the server*/
  $handler = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

  $errors = array();
  session_start();
  /** To perform authentication of login with the database*/

  if(empty($_POST['username'])){
        $this->errors[] = "Username field was empty.";
  } elseif (empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $this->errors[] = "Password field was empty.";
  }
  elseif(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){   
   $user=$_POST['username'];  
   $pass=$_POST['password'];  

   $handler or die(mysqli_error());  
   mysqli_select_db($handler,'users') or die("Cannot select DB");  

   $query=mysqli_query($handler,"SELECT Username,Email,Password 
    FROM person WHERE username='".$user."' OR email='".$user."'");  
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);  
    /**The old code is stated below here
    if ($result_of_login_check->num_rows == 1)
     */
     /**The Problem Starts here*/
     if ($numrows ==1){  
     if (password_verify($_POST['password']) {
     // write user data into PHP SESSION (a file on your 
     server)
     /**The Problem Starts here*/
     $_SESSION['user_name'] = $result_row->user_name;
     $_SESSION['user_email'] = $result_row->user_email;
     $_SESSION['user_login_status'] = 1;
     } else {
     $query->errors[] = "Wrong password or username. Try again.";
     }
     } 
     } 
     ?>
```

Comment: its probably stopping at `password_verify` as your using it wrong, it should be spitting out errors. if it's not, then you need to make sure error checking and display are on  at the top of your php page add: `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); ini_set('html_errors', 0); error_reporting(-1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<?php session_start(); ?>` try this to top of login.php and make sure you have start session on every page

```
<?php session_start();?>
<?php
$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
/** Define variable to perform connection to the server*/
$handler = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);
$errors = array();

/** To perform authentication of login with the database*/
if(empty($_POST['username'])){
$this->errors[] = "Username field was empty.";
} elseif (empty($_POST['password'])) {
$this->errors[] = "Password field was empty.";
}
elseif(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
$user=$_POST['username'];
$pass=$_POST['password'];
$handler or die(mysqli_error());
mysqli_select_db($handler,'users') or die("Cannot select DB");
$query=mysqli_query($handler,"SELECT Username,Email,Password
FROM person WHERE username='".$user."' OR email='".$user."'");
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
/**The old code is stated below here
if ($result_of_login_check->num_rows == 1)
*/
/**The Problem Starts here*/
if ($numrows ==1){
if (password_verify($_POST['password']) {
// write user data into PHP SESSION (a file on your
server)
/**The Problem Starts here*/
$_SESSION['user_name'] = $result_row->user_name;
$_SESSION['user_email'] = $result_row->user_email;
$_SESSION['user_login_status'] = 1;
} else {
$query->errors[] = "Wrong password or username. Try again.";
}
}
}
?>
```